# How to solve Preg_match warning?

Tags: preg-match

I am using preg_match function in my program. The code is like this

```
if (!$this->config_allow_src_above_docroot && !preg_match('^'.preg_quote(str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', realpath($this->config_document_root))), $AbsoluteFilename))
```

But run the application it shows the warning like this

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^'
```

Can you help me please..

Answer (score 0):

You must add pattern delimiters:

```
preg_match('/^' . preg_quote(str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', realpath($this->config_document_root))) . '/', $AbsoluteFilename)
            ^                                                                                                 ^
```

Since you have forgotten to put delimiters in your pattern, the regex engine believes that `^` is the starting delimiter and is surprised to not found the same delimiter at the end of the pattern.